# Bootstrap tabs routing with summyjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-tabs

i found a way to route bootstrap tabs with summyjs, but it doent seem to be in line with the samples i have seen. i just started learning summyjs and i dont like how i did it, though it works...
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <meta name="" content=""/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Other/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Other/bootstrap.css">
        <style>
            html {
              position: relative;
              min-height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                font-family: 'Lato', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px; 
                color: #222;
            }
            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
            body {
              margin-top: 20px;
              padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h2 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Using Summyjs to route Bootstrap Tabs</h2>
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" href="#">My Resume</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div style="" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified"> 
                   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">PERSONAL SUMMARY</a> </li> 
                   <li><a href="#ios" data-toggle="tab">AREAS OF EXPERIENCE</a></li> 
                   <li><a href="#jmeter" data-toggle="tab">CAREER SKILLS</a> </li> 
                   <li><a href="#ejb" data-toggle="tab">PERSONAL DETAILS</a> </li> 
                </ul> 
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>


            <div style="padding-top: 20px;" id="myTabContent" class="tab-content"> 

                <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
                <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home"> 
                  <p>Tutorials Point is a place for beginners in all technical areas.  
                     This website covers most of the latest technoligies and explains           each of the technology with simple examples. You also have a           <b>tryit</b> editor, wherein you can edit your code and           try out different possibilities of the examples.</p> 
               </div> 



               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ios"> 
                  <p>iOS is a mobile operating system developed and distributed by Apple  
                     Inc. Originally released in 2007 for the iPhone, iPod Touch, and  
                     Apple TV. iOS is derived from OS X, with which it shares the  
                     Darwin foundation. iOS is Apple's mobile version of the  
                     OS X operating system used on Apple computers.</p> 
               </div> 



               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="jmeter"> 
                  <p>jMeter is an Open Source testing software. It is 100% pure  
                  Java application for load and performance testing.</p> 
               </div> 



               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
               <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ejb"> 
                  <p>Enterprise Java Beans (EJB) is a development architecture           for building highly scalable and robust enterprise level     
                     applications to be deployed on J2EE compliant           Application Server such as JBOSS, Web Logic etc. 
                  </p> 
               </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="Other/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="Other/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Other/summyjs/min/sammy-0.7.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Update the URL with the current tabs hash
        $("#myTab a").click(function () { location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });


        function ShowTab(tabname) {
            //Show the selected tab
            $('#myTab a[href="#' + tabname + '"]').tab('show');
        }

        // Client-side routes    
        Sammy(function () {
            this.get('#:selectedtab', function () {

                ShowTab(this.params.selectedtab);
            });

            //default to the first tab if there is no hash in the URL
            this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#home') });
        }).run();

    </script>
</html>
```

help me learn symmy assisting me solve this...
what i want is to do routing in a better wat than the below script...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            //Update the URL with the current tabs hash
            $("#myTab a").click(function () { location.hash = $(this).attr('href'); });


            function ShowTab(tabname) {
                //Show the selected tab
                $('#myTab a[href="#' + tabname + '"]').tab('show');
            }

            // Client-side routes    
            Sammy(function () {
                this.get('#:selectedtab', function () {

                    ShowTab(this.params.selectedtab);
                });

                //default to the first tab if there is no hash in the URL
                this.get('', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#home') });
            }).run();

        </script>
```

Comment: Can you pare down your code sample? Narrow it down to the problem area, and sort it out by HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but only the relevant parts. Don't simply paste what looks like your entire page into your question.

Comment: You really didn't....

Comment: even though i dont currently know alot about summyjs routing becouse am still learning, i really dont like the way that script is handling routing, so i want like a better way to do it...